# How to fix circular dependency between functions?

Tags: c, circular-dependency

I'm working on a feature for an embedded device where I need to check if a power supply is on. The problem I have is that in one of the hardware versions, two power supplies are dependent on one another due to a HW mistake.

I have this function in one file:

```
bool sensor_power_supply_is_on() {
    if (is_spi_shared_between_sensors_and_flash() == true) {
        return (m_sensor_power.state == 1) && flash_power_supply_is_on();
    }

    return (m_sensor_power.state == 1);
}
```

And this one in another:

```
bool flash_power_supply_is_on() {
    if (is_spi_shared_between_sensors_and_flash() == true) {
        return (m_flash_power.state == 1) && sensor_power_supply_is_on();
    }

    return (m_flash_power.state == 1);
}
```

If I use this code when `is_spi_shared_between_sensors_and_flash()` returns `true` then the functions call themselves recursively.

How do I get around this dependency? I figured I could do a wrapper function of sorts, but I can't really think of how.

EDIT: The problem is not about forward declarations, but rather about how to restructure the code to avoid infinite recursion.

EDIT: I would like to keep the `m_` variables static (private to each file). To get around this I could create a getter function but I would also not like to do that as other modules wouldn't necessarily know what `flash_power_state = x` means.

Comment: Just stop calling the functions and do the m_flash_power and m_sensor_power comparisons in both. They are both comparing the same things.

Comment: I guess I could make the variables global to avoid the function calls, but I'd prefer to keep the `m_` variables static.

Comment: Well these are two separate function calls returning two separate values. You also could maybe put if statements where the functions are actually used to call a specific one. Then get rid of the internal function loop.

Answer (score 2):

In the end I decided to create another function like this:

```
bool sensor_power_supply_is_on() {
    return (m_sensor_power.state == 1);
}

bool sensor_power_supply_is_ready() {
    if (is_spi_shared_between_sensors_and_flash() == true) {
        return sensor_power_supply_is_on() && flash_power_supply_is_on();
    }

    return sensor_power_supply_is_on();
}
```

Same thing on the flash file.

```
bool flash_power_supply_is_on() {
    return (m_flash_power.state == 1);
}

bool flash_power_supply_is_ready() {
    if (is_spi_shared_between_sensors_and_flash() == true) {
        return flash_power_supply_is_on() && sensor_power_supply_is_on();
    }

    return flash_power_supply_is_on();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try limit each function to a maximum number of recursive runs

```
bool flash_power_supply_is_on(int n) {
    if (n) {
        if (is_spi_shared_between_sensors_and_flash() == true) {
            return (m_flash_power.state == 1) && sensor_power_supply_is_on(n - 1);
            //                                                             ^^^^^
        }
        return (m_flash_power.state == 1);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Then you'd call it with, maybe, `if (flash_power_supply_is_on(512)) /* do something */;`

Answer (score 0):

If `is_spi_shared_between_sensors_and_flash()` is true, both functions call the other function, which amounts to add an extra check for `m_<the other>_power.state` in that very case:

Just do:

```
bool sensor_power_supply_is_on() {
    bool retval = m_sensor_power.state == 1;

    if (is_spi_shared_between_sensors_and_flash()) {
        return retval && (m_flash_power.state == 1);
    }

    return retval;
}

bool flash_power_supply_is_on() {
    bool retval = m_flash_power.state == 1;

    if (is_spi_shared_between_sensors_and_flash()) {
        return retval && (m_sensor_power.state == 1);
    }

    return retval;
}
```

Comment: I could make the variables global to avoid the function calls, but I'd prefer to keep the `m_` variables static. I could also probably add a getter but that's also something that I wouldn't like to do since other modules wouldn't necessarily know what those states mean.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the struct member `m_flash_power.state` instead of the function `flash_power_supply_is_on()`:

```
bool sensor_power_supply_is_on() {
    if (is_spi_shared_between_sensors_and_flash() == true) {
        return (m_sensor_power.state == 1) && (m_flash_power.state == 1);     // Use struct instead of function call
    }
    return (m_sensor_power.state == 1);
}
```

Comment: @andresovela: Why did you decide on using a function instead of using the struct directly? Your function just accesses/returns the value of struct member which adds unnecessary overhead compared to directly accessing e.g. `m_sensor_power.state`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
bool sensor_power_supply_is_on() {
    if (is_spi_shared_between_sensors_and_flash() == true) {
        return (m_sensor_power.state == 1) && (m_flash_power.state == 1);
    }

    return (m_sensor_power.state == 1);
}

bool flash_power_supply_is_on() {
    if (is_spi_shared_between_sensors_and_flash() == true) {
        return (m_flash_power.state == 1) && (m_sensor_power.state == 1);
    }

    return (m_flash_power.state == 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the functions are rather simple, just do both checks in each function:

```
bool sensor_power_supply_is_on() {
    boot ret = m_sensor_power.state == 1
    if (is_spi_shared_between_sensors_and_flash() == true) {
        ret &= m_flash_power.state == 1;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Similar for the second function.